# vue - select option change triggers vuex mutation error

Tags: select, vuejs2, vue.js, vuex

I'm using vue2.
I want to get select option object in v-for

HTML:

```
       <select
        class="custom-select"
        @change="onPlanSelected($event)"
        v-model="selectedPlan.objectId">
        <option
          v-for="plan in plans"
          :key="plan.objectId"
          :value="plan.objectId">
          {{ plan.title }}
        </option>
      </select>
```

JS:

```
data () {
  return {
    selectedPlan: {}
  }
}

onPlanSelected (event) {
  this.selectedPlan = this.plans.find(plan => {
    return plan.objectId === event.target.value
  })
}
```

when I change the select option, I get the error:

[image]

As you can see selectedPlan is data not vuex.

Btw, how to get an object from a select v-for option

Thanks

Comment: Are you changing any vuex store variable somewhere:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I don't see the need of using `@change` in your case. `v-model` should be sufficient for handling the selected option. 
Here is a sample fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z11fe07p/567/

As long as you have the whole object as `:value` and `v-model` as well you always have the selected option along with it's id.

Comment: thx, its work!  looks like I didn't get it in select option by vue.